# Monoidal categories are one-0-cell bicategories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, bicategories

I just saw this definition/interpretation of monoidal categories and I have two questions about it.

The idea is to consider the objects of the monoidal category as 1-cells and the tensor product as 2-cells.

- Where are the morphisms of the monoidal category?

---

Thinking of $\mathcal{Cat}$ as bicategory, string diagrams in it draw 0-cells as two dimensional spaces, 1-cells as one dimensional strings between the spaces, and 2-cells as zero dimensional points on the strings.

But I don't see how this is the same as with string diagrams for monoidal categories ---if we want to think of them as bicategories with one 0-cell---, where objects are strings and morphisms are dots. (There may be different two dimensional spaces but only one 0-cell.)

- What is happening here? Is there a more general way to interpret string diagrams that encompass both ways or is there actually a way to think of string diagrams for monoidal categories as string diagrams for bicategories with one object? Or just how should I think about it?

---

Let's call the potential interpretation of string diagrams for bicategories I gave above *bi-string diagrams*, and the interpretation of string diagrams for monoidal categories I gave above *tensor-string diagrams*.

Being explicit, a *bi-string diagram* is drawing 0-cells as spaces, 1-cells as strings and 2-cells as dots; wheareas a *tensor-string diagram* is drawing objects as strings and morphisms as dots.

I must note that I assumed that bi-string diagrams are drawn this way by analogy with $\mathcal {Cat}$, but I'm not sure it's actually this way in general.

I do realize that bi-string diagrams for $\mathcal{Cat}$ can also be interpreted as tensor-string diagrams for the functor category with horizontal composition as tensor product. (Hence the name horizontal.) So it is not clear which interpretation (bi- or tensor-) is more general.

---

I'm a bit confused with all of this so I might be making some profound mistakes, and so I'm sorry if that's the case.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The tensor product is the composition of 1-cells. The morphisms are the 2-cells. There are two Poincare dual ways to draw the string diagrams.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that makes so much more sense, thanks. I still don't see the only 0-cell as a two dimensional space. Can you make a comment about that?

Comment: @Julián See [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Commutative_diagram_to_string_diagram.svg/1920px-Commutative_diagram_to_string_diagram.svg.png). The morphisms now go between the regions they separate (right to left). The 2-morphism goes between the lines emerging from it (top to bottom).

Comment: @DanielTeixeira hey, thanks for the comment. I finally see what I was misinterpreting and it was not that hard. Cheers!